# Yahrzeit in different time zone

Tags: calendar, yahrtzeit, time-zone

If a person passes away in one place but [some] relatives live in another place in which, due to time zone differences, it is already the next day (or still the previous), do those relatives establish the yahrzeit based on the date in the place where the person died, or where they live (and where the person will be buried -- assuming that the yahrzeit is based on death, not interment)?

Is it possible that different relatives would mark different days as the yahrzeit or do they all accept one date regardless of where they live?

Comment: Why would you think so about Yahrzeit: *"do those relatives establish the yahrzeit "*? I would think about Shiv'ah before/after sunset in different zones, but Y. seems to clearly follow the deceased.

Comment: I already know that shiva can be computed differently for different people based on a funeral, an interment, travel and time zones but I don't know if any of these has an effect on the Yahrzeit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93875/discussion-between-al-berko-and-rosends).

Comment: I heard s story of a person who missed yartzeit and so they called up a shul several time zones over to say Kaddish for him.

Comment: @mroll that begs the question of whether, if I ask a representative to say kaddish on yahrzeits in the future, I have to make sure they apply the requests to prayers during the tefillot which correlate to the "home" time zones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**TorahMusings**](https://www.torahmusings.com/) article titled "[Yahrzeit Practices](https://www.torahmusings.com/2014/07/yahrtzeit-practices/)" cites the opinion of the   **Gesher Hachaim** (volume 1, 32:14) who writes:

> If the person died in a different time zone than his relative, the yahrtzeit is determined based on the time and location of the person who died, independent of where the relatives may be.

**TorahMusings** acknowledges that not everyone agrees to this, noting in footnote #14:

> See however **Penei Baruch** 39:40 who cites other opinions as well